# Whenever I try to open the excel generated file from JAVA,I am able to view contenets only if I disable Protected View in Excel

Tags: java, excel, windows

I am debugging a complex java application where an excel file with extension .xls is created.Whenever I try to open the excel generated file,I am able to view contenets only if I disable Protected View in Excel 2013.The OS used is windows latest.

Any suggestions?

Comment: My question is all about java layer creating excel file...I agree that there is a MS OFFICE security advice.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the file is being interpreted as foreign or malicious even though it is from your computer.

Have you seen this?  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/What-is-Protected-View-d6f09ac7-e6b9-4495-8e43-2bbcdbcb6653

Look at "I want to change my Protected View Settings" to verify what setting(s) are causing this.

Comment: Thank you,But is there a way to drive the settings in excel file while creating xls file from java layer?

Answer (score 0):

After debugging it thoroughly,it seems we can generate xls file over java http url request(can be catered by a script ) on the fly.We just need to play with 'content-disposition' while setting header and ensure correct MIME type for excel.File name is determined automatically.

The issue which I faced was that we were copying html table content as it is to an excel file and we were able to open the excel file in any text editor to see the html contents.Logically speaking,if we want to see the content atleast before dsiabling proected mode,opening an excel file in any text editor should display binary content.If it is not showing binary content,MS OFFICE will always throw such security checks.

So,use apache POI/openCSV to create a xls file from either html/csv file and try opening it.We can always get a binary content if we open it in text editor...Hope this helps everyone...